# ADF Add Header to CSV Sink

Tags: azure-data-factory

Anyone know how to add header to csv sink? I have a data flow that's source is a database table. Then I have used derived column and concatenated the columns to make one column and split the data in the column by commas (done in the source via a query). I have then selected the column that has been concatenated to be export to csv.

Data example:

```
Matt,Smith,10
```

Therefore I technically only have one column, however, I want to add a header for each section of the data.

Desired output:

```
FirstName,LastName,Age
Matt,Smith,10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add headers in CSV file.

Select Data Flow Activity.

Select Source and use Select activity.

Add column names as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Finally add Sink and run Pipeline.

Comment: this didn't work for me. In the CSV dataset I have 'first row as header' box checked. When I open the CSV file there is no header in the file

Comment: Please uncheck 'first row as header' box. Then follow steps given in above answer. You have to manually add column names as shown in above answer.

Comment: I have unchecked the header box and still am not getting a header in the csv file

Comment: any further comments to why it's still not working?